# Storing data in .txt file and retrieving it

Tags: python, authentication, txt

I was trying to make some sort of login system,
I have it so that if a username and password are in test.txt (there is multiple ones) it should let you login, I haven't even passed the step of verifying if the username and password are in the txt file and its destroying me, I don't know how to do it and I tried for hours, I made it so "if you find this username in the text file, give me the line number and check if the password this password is in the same line of the username ,(I used split (',')) , if both email and password entered are existent in the txt file and in the same line then..(didn't do that yet).

so it is confusing me, lots of errors, if no errors then it isn't working like I intended, here is my spaghetti code

```
def test():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for num, line in enumerate(f,1):
            username = line.split(',')
            if username in num:
                 if username == q1:
                    print("found user in line: " + num)
                    Line = num
                    password = line.split(',')
                    if password in Line:
                        if password == q2:
                            print("found pass in line: " + num)
```

can someone help me fix this and explain to me how storing data in .txt files work and how to retrieve them? YouTube and google didn't help much really, if you can suggest a video that will be cool too, because I'm confused at this point, all I have left is to try MongoDB because it has functions to retrieve data and store it already built in

but as its local on my pc not on the internet, I don't think I will need MongoDB, so that will be an overkill for a local test

Comment: Why do you prefer a text file to store user info? You can use a json file instead.

Comment: Or since is built into Python, Sqlite3.

Comment: json could be a life saver in this, but i thought it only worked with JavaScript, and idk about Sqlite as it is more of an extension and i am trying to be a little vanilla, so if json works i would love to try it out (i dont know how to use it in python) and if there is a way i could learn the .txt way that would be awesome

Comment: i used to use .json files to check for stuff in js, i didnt even know that i can edit it through code, thats why i always used to use mongodb

Comment: Sqlite3(sqlite3) is part of the standard library as is JSON(json). That is about as vanilla as you can get.

Comment: oh,  i need to do some research on Sqlite3, i guess i dont understand it much, and json too if i will use it, i could make a collection in a json file right? and get its values from a py file, and append stuff to it, because if thats possible, i think that will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With json, you can get it done this way:

> JSON File

```
{
"user1":{"password":"123456"},
"user2":{"password": "abcde"}
}
```

> Python

```
import json

def test(username, password):
    with open("answer.json", "r") as read_it: 
        data = json.load(read_it) 
    if data[username][password] == '123456':
        print('User found!')
    else:
        print('User or password doesn\'t exist')
          
 test('user1', 'password')
```

Comment: Thanks! ill also try that out tomorrow as i am really tired today, but what if i want to append more users, and i see that the password is hardcoded in the .py file, is there a way to not hardcode it and use "input("question")" for that? also , this is looking for the password and not confirming that the user entered is right, how do i fix that in summary, i am trying to make it get input of user and password, if both are found in file and right then it lets you enter, if not it suggests registration (where it will be "appended" or smt) in the json

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a text file, then as a simple example:

```
cat test.txt 

aklaver, dog
adrian, cat
alklaver, fish

user_name = 'aklaver'

with open('test.txt', 'r') as pwd_file:
    lines = pwd_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        user, pwd = line.split(',')
        if user == user_name:
            print(pwd)

dog
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try Squilt3, JSON, text, tmr , and ill use what works best for me, now im tired so i wont be able to do it